# WinJS notification when binding was performed

Tags: javascript, mvvm, binding, windows-8, winjs

In my windows 8 WinJS app, I have a view populated with a viewModel. ViewModel contains observable property (via WinJS.Binding.as) which is bound to text input in my HTML view. When I change value of this property from my viewModel, value of text input changes, however "onchange" event for this text input is not fired.

Is there a way to know the exact moment when binding was performed? Why is "onchange" event not fired? I would like to react to changes to view made from viewModel in view's code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question looked not very clear. some of these details might help you.

1. WinJS does not support two way binding. Only binding from viewmodel to view is supported. other way round - view to view model - is not supported. you will need to listen to the 'change' event explicitly on the input element - and handle it.
2. If you are looking for event when an observable property changes, you can consider using [bind method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211857.aspx).

   ```
   var p = { name: 'martin' };
   var o = WinJS.Binding.as(p);
   o.bind('name', function onnamechange(newValue, oldValue)
   {
       console.log('property changed: ', oldValue, newValue);
   });
   o.name = 'mark';
   ```
3. To listen to changes in input element, you can listen for 'change' event.

   ```
   inputElement.addEventListener('change', function(evt)
   {
       // your code here.
   });
   ```

Comment: I implemented my own twoway binding - I am able to react to changes in viewModel in view and vice versa. My question is - how do I react to change made to viewModel in view's code behind? E. g. I have text input in my view which is bound to viewModel's property. When I change property in viewModel, text input's value changes in view - I'd like to listen to text input's change in view's code behind.

Comment: Ok, after some testing, solution mentioned in point 2) is a way to go. I did something like that in my view's code behind: viewModels.myViewModel.bind("myProperty", myHandler). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the "change" event since it is fired only when the input loses focus and the value is changed. You cannot use the "input" event because it fires on "keydown". Check the documentation for these two events:

Change: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441307.aspx

Input: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj569354.aspx

What you can use is the "onpropertychange" event. I tried it and for some reason it does not work with addEventListener(), but it works with attachEvent().

```
inpt.attachEvent("onpropertychange", function (e) {
    if (e.propertyName == "value") {
        inpt.style.background = "red";
    }
})
```

It is important to check the propertyName, because otherwise the event will be fired in a loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, attachEvent method doesn't exist (as I read on the web it is depreciated) and as you mentioned addEventListener() doesn't work. I am using WinJS 2.0 (Windows 8.1 target) - maybe that's why attachEvent method no longer exists.

Comment: Yes, WinJS 2.0 uses IE11's JS engine and apparently the solution I provided is very slow, so they dropped it. They are replacing "propertychange" with Mutation Observers. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265032(v=vs.85).aspx

And yes, the solution by Sushil to listen for object changes is much better.